# syntax error python 3.4 tetris game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

```
def check_block( self, (x, y) ):

    """
    Check if the x, y coordinate can have a block placed there.
    That is; if there is a 'landed' block there or it is outside the
    board boundary, then return False, otherwise return true.
    """
    if x < 0 or x >= self.max_x or y < 0 or y >= self.max_y:
        return False
    elif self.landed.has_key( (x, y) ):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Here there is syntax error in `def` part, `(x,y)`... So how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [tuple parameter unpacking was removed in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

So this code

```
def foo(x, (y, z)):
    print(x, y, z)

foo(1, (2, 3))
```

Works in Python 2.7

```
>>> python2 test.py 
(1, 2, 3)
```

but fails in Python 3

```
>>> python3 test.py 
  File "test.py", line 2
    def foo(x, (y, z)):
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can also see this with the `-3` option in Python 2:

```
>>> python2 -3 test.py 
test.py:2: SyntaxWarning: tuple parameter unpacking has been removed in 3.x
  def foo(x, (y, z)):
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#no-loss-of-abilities-if-removed) of the page tobias links to explains how you should update your code.